# Le piment est chaud / épicé

Tags: usage, alimentation

In English, you can say a dish is hot and spicy. "Hot" refers to the burning sensation from chilli and "spicy" is being flavoured with or fragrant with spice.

I know in Khmer you have a specific word for hotness of chilli and another for temperature. Using the "hot" for temperature when referring to dishes will not make sense.

In French, is it valid to use "chaud" to refer to hotness of chillis (i.e. the burning sensation and not temperature)? Is there a one-to-one equivalent translation of "hot and spicy"?

Comment: And if people ask you if you like to 'manger épicé', you can reply 'Never at the same time'. I'll show myself out....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can say that the right word, as far as culinary art is concerned, appears nowhere in your question. The term for "hot" would be more specifically "piquant": a hot spicy food → de la nourriture fortement épicée; one is never too sure what is meant by "épicé": it can be "piquant" (that is stinging on the tongue and palate) or it can mean that it has strong spices, such as curry that isn't spicy in the way that hurts your mouth.

For the time being, "chaud" is to be banished from your French vocabulary in the way of rendering the adjective "hot", except in the context of actual heat, as corrected @Luke Sawczak in the comments.

- the electric line is hot → "il y a le (du) courant" ou (substandard) "il y a le jus"
- hot news → nouvelles de première page

However, you might — before long if not already — be able to translate "hotline" by "ligne chaude" and similarly for a few others. "Hotline" is now part of the French vocabulary.

Comment: Banished, except in the context of actual heat :)

Comment: or in expressions like "(s)he is so hot !"

Comment: never heard of "ligne chaude" for hotline, though

Comment: and hot news would rather be "les dernières nouvelles"

Comment: @radouxju I do say "you might before long", not that it should be found in dictionaries; I say that it is possible before long because le phrase has appeared on billboard like surfaces; so there are already people using it in the French business world.

Comment: ok, je n'avais pas compris toute la nuance de la phrase en anglais

Comment: @radouxju I do not quite agree, in fact I don't. "les dernières nouvelles" are not quite what you call in standard English "headline breaking news" and in American English possibly "hot news"; rather "les denières nouvelles" which incidentally can be "hot news" are merely  the reporting of a new turn that  is suddenly taking a topic that's been talked about in the news for some time. It is often not important for a lot of people (Tu connais les dernières nouvelles? Ils vont nous augmenter les cigarettes de 50 %...). However, ( factual and often), it means "what's just been heard in the news".

Comment: based on your explanation, I would say "la une" (faire la une des journaux = being the most important topic"). I thought that "hot" was used in the sense of "the latest" (still "hot" from the printing machine)

Comment: @radouxju You're right, and that's a term you should use if you're in the news business or a writer of some sort and at that in certain cases only (that's more difficult to determine) but the non specialised people, that is the people at large, would rather say "la première page", "en première page"; "la une" belongs in great part to journalistic jargon and might as other terms of that sort that the "real" people do not use, never gain legitimacy.

Answer (score 4):

> In French, is it valid to use "chaud" to refer to hotness of chillis (i.e. the burning sensation and not temperature)?

It is more than unlikely to be used. *Chaud* essentially relates to the food temperature when applying to dishes. However, we might say *en feu* to describe the feeling: *[avoir la bouche en feu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_la_bouche_en_feu).*

> Is there a one-to-one equivalent translation of "hot and spicy"?

We use ***fort*** (strong, opposed to *doux*: sweet/soft) for hot food like in ***moutarde forte***/douce or ***piment fort***/doux so "hot and spicy chillies" would be *piments **forts et épicés***.

We also have an adjective that encompass both hot and spicy when referring to a dish: *[**relevé**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relev%C3%A9#2)*

> Ce plat est (très) relevé.

Note that while *picante* is the main word used to translate *hot (chillies)* in Spanish ([as you already know](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27186/is-it-valid-to-use-caliente-to-refer-to-hotness-of-chillis-is-there-a-one-to)) and *fuerte* a much less used alternative, this is the opposite with the French corresponding words *piquant* and *fort*.

Spanish:

[image]

French:

[image]

On the other hand, when qualifying sauces, *piquantes* is leading in French too:

[image]

Comment: Il ne faut pas confondre « épicé » (qui a du goût grâce à des épices, pas nécessairement du piment) et « pimenté » (qui est fort en goût). Il n'y a que très peu d'épices qui sont pimentées (de mémoire : le piment, le poivre, le gingembre il me semble qu'il en existe une quatrième dont je ne me souviens plus du nom)

Comment: Oui. *Épicé* est quand même souvent utilisé en incluant le sens de *pimenté*.

Comment: Je suis bien d'accord, c'est juste pour préciser.

Comment: L'adjectif _fort_, comme dans _piment fort_, est à mon avis essentiel à une réponse, en particulier pour un apprenant. +1 Merci.

Answer (score 3):

Pour un plat piquant à cause d'un piment, on peut aussi utiliser l'adjectif "pimenté", tout simplement. L'adjectif "relevé" est aussi une solution. Par contre, je confirme que "chaud" ne s'emploie pas dans ce contexte.

En ce qui concerne la température, il me semble que "hot" correspond à une température élevée (mais je ne suis pas anglophone). Je traduirais donc par "brûlant" (pour un plat solide) ou "bouillant" (pour un plat liquide) si le but est de prévenir une brûlure de la langue en mangeant.

Answer (score 2):

Shame on me for thinking it necessary to offer some colorful (read: “arguably gutter-talk”) options to go with all the excellent answers given so far, but the often not-so-nice (when applied to humans) word [*gueule*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/gueule) (= *la bouche*= “mouth”), figures in several descriptive French expressions I’ve heard/used involving spicy hot foods (and the strong/harsh alcohols of my youth).

> [**Ça/Cela arrache la
>   gueule**](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%87a%20arrache%20!) =
>   *c'est très pimenté* = “That'll take the roof of your mouth off!”
>    (from *WordReference.com*), …

from which [(according to ‘viera’  in this WordReference thread)](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tarrache-la-gueule.223182/) the adjective …

> **arrache-gueule** is [apparently derived and] commonly used as an adjective to refer to very hot (spicy) food.
>   "Cette sauce est plutôt
>   arrache-gueule."

---

---

Although more for describing one's ability to tolerate/stomach/enjoy such food than for describing the food itself, from the French Academy’s Dictionary entry for “gueule” (at the link provided in paragraph 1 above, via *CNRTL*), there’s:

**Avoir la gueule pavée** = être capable d'avaler des aliments très épicés ou très chauds.*

And according to [this *mediadico.com* entry for "gueule,](http://www.mediadico.com/dictionnaire/definition/gueule/)

**Avoir la gueule ferrée** can have the same meaning as the above expression using *pavée*.

(both of which could translate to "Having mouths/pie holes/gullets lined with steel" in English)